# How to calculate log likelihood?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $Y_i = f(x_i, \theta)+\epsilon_i$, for  $i=1,...,n$, where $f$ is everywhere differentiable and the errors $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ are i.i.d as $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. How can I derive the expression for the log likelihood  $l(x,\theta)$ given only this small amount of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $Y_i$, we have:

$$\log L(\theta|Y_i)= -\frac{\log 2\pi\sigma^2}{2}+\frac{-(Y_i-f(\theta))^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

If you have an iid sample of $n$, then it becomes:

$$\log L(\theta|\mathbf{Y},n)= -\frac{n\log 2\pi\sigma^2}{2}+\sum_{1}^N \frac{-(Y_i-f(\theta))^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

This is as far as you can get until you have a specific form for $f(\theta)$

However, as a side note: whatever $f$ is, the MLE for $\theta$ will be the least squares estimate...this is due to the normally distributed error term.